# Sync iCloud bookmarks with Firefox in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, firefox, bookmarks, icloud

I have four devices that I want to sync my bookmarks across: a Mac Mini, a Macbook Air, an iPad2, and a Windows 7 PC.

I use Safari on the three Apple products and Firefox 8 on the Windows 7 PC. I use iCloud to sync my bookmarks with the three Apple devices, but this obviously leaves my Windows PC out of the loop. I realize that I can sync the bookmarks to IE and then constantly export them and import them into Firefox, but this is both clunky and not really a "sync" since things that I bookmark on my PC in Firefox won't show up on my other devices.

What is the best way to sync my bookmarks from iCloud with a PC running Firefox 8?

Comment: As described, it's not possible without some hack or intermediate method, like using IE.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an add-on or something similar that I was unaware of that would handle this in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Xmarks can be combined with iCloud. I use XMarks on Windows machine and on OS X machine. Using iCloud on OS X machine and iPad. I get all bookmarks synchronized on all devices. Drawback is that you need to synchronize on OS X in order to sync between Windows and iPad. But in my case this is not a problem since my Mac Mini is up most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use the Firefox extension "plainoldfavorites". The IE bookmarks are then directly accessible from Firefox and no export/import is necessary. And the IE bookmarks are directly sync'd to iCloud.